# Updating variables in the watch command in bash

Tags: bash, watch

I have a series of directories with names in a sequence (i.e. 001 002 003 ... 999). I am running a job that works on the contents in each directory, ascending the sequence from 001 to 999. The job will echo into an output.txt file in each directory. When the job has finished working on the content in a directory, it echoes "running DIRECTORY_NAME" to the  job_status.txt file in the parent directory and moves on to work on the next directory.

I would like to run a simple command that looks at the output.txt of the directory that the job is currently running in.

I tried

```
watch "i=$(tail -n 1 job_status.txt | awk '{print $2}'); tail $i/output.txt"
```

This works initially; however, when the job moves on to a new directory, $i in the watch command is not updated and I'm stuck looking at the output file from the directory that the job has already completed.

How can I solve this issue?

Many thanks

Jacek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're expanding the variable even before watch executes. Use a single quote instead:

```
watch 'i=$(awk "END { print \$2 }" job_status.txt); tail "$i/output.txt"'
```

Watch calls `sh -c` when executing the command, so define the command as if you're calling it with `sh`.

Comment: This works. Thanks! But what if "running DIRECTORY_NAME" is echoed into the job_status.txt? Using ````watch 'tail -n 1 job_status.txt | awk "{print $2}"); tail $i/output.txt'```` will lead to the same problem.

Comment: @Jacek `watch 'i=$(awk "END { print \"\$2\" }"); tail "$i/output.txt"'`

Comment: This gives an error ````cannot open `$2/output.txt' for reading: No such file or directory````

Comment: it seems the ````awk 'END {print $2}'```` only works if it is using single quote. Then it raises the question of how to put this single quote inside the single quote of the watch command. I've modified the question to include the "running DIRECOTRY_NAME" problem

Comment: @Jacek Right. The quotes weren't needed there: `watch 'i=$(awk "END { print \$2 }"); tail "$i/output.txt"'`

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem, but you missed the "job_status.txt" in your reply. Can you modify your answer so I can accept it for the modified question? Many thanks!